# What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

The Windows FINDSTR command is horribly documented. There is very basic command line help available through `FINDSTR /?`, or `HELP FINDSTR`, but it is woefully inadequate. There is a wee bit more documentation online at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr.

There are many FINDSTR features and limitations that are not even hinted at in the documentation. Nor could they be anticipated without prior knowledge and/or careful experimentation.

So the question is - **What are the undocumented FINDSTR features and limitations?**

The purpose of this question is to provide a one stop repository of the many undocumented features so that:

A) Developers can take full advantage of the features that are there.

B) Developers don't waste their time wondering why something doesn't work when it seems like it should.

Please make sure you know the existing documentation before responding. If the information is covered by the HELP, then it does not belong here.

Neither is this a place to show interesting uses of FINDSTR. If a logical person could anticipate the behavior of a particular usage of FINDSTR based on the documentation, then it does not belong here.

Along the same lines, if a logical person could anticipate the behavior of a particular usage based on information contained in any existing answers, then again, it does not belong here.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you could ditch the crappy undocumented MS utility altogether and install/use `grep` which _is_ very well understood and documented :-) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635740/why-does-findstr-not-handle-case-properly-in-some-circumstances for example.

Comment: By all means, if you are in a position to use something other than FINDSTR, then that is highly advised. But some people are in environments where 3rd party utilities are forbidden.

Comment: I wasn't trying to denigrate the question, dbenham, in fact it's quite useful (as is the _comprehensive_ answer) which is why I +1'ed them. I was just stating that people who don't want to muck about with horrible software have other (better) choices. Well, those that don't have brain-dead corporate policies :-).

Comment: No offense taken. I seriously considered putting in my own FINDSTR disclaimer that was similar to your comment! :)

Comment: I am shocked and dissapointed someone would find this question "Not Constructive" and vote to close. A lot of thought went into the question specifically to avoid "opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". The question has been posted for 3.5 months, and none of the negatives cited have occurred. The paired answer is filled with facts, and required many hours of painstaking research and experimentation.

Comment: Some readers may be interested in the historical context of the findstr command: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/11/28/10372436.aspx

Comment: @dbenham, Not me, but according to SE's flawed rules, this is a "list" type of question which is clearly not allowed. If it's on-topic, it's on-topic and if it's not, it's not.  There are tons of questions with "painstaking research and experimentation" that will be off-topic here. But glad that you're a "high rep". Had the same exact question byte-for-byte be posted by someone without "high rep", it'll be closed in 10 mins and downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: @Pacerier - At the time this Q was posted, I had only been a member for just over 2 months, with a rep around 2000. The SO rules are constantly evolving - definitely not a black and white world, but many shades of gray. For example, at the time of writing, there was a (now banned) [hidden-features] tag that had frequently been used (and abused.)  I knew the Q was risky (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118071/176331), but I thought the information had value, so I worked hard on the Q phrasing and A content. Based on the Q&A score and number of views, I think I succeeded.

Comment: See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151209-00/?p=92361) for a history of why `findstr` doesn't use the standard regular expression library.

Comment: [Thanks to Simon Sheppard](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) for creating this easy reference.

Comment: @Abhijeet - If you are implying that Simon was the originator of this content - No, it is the other way around. Notice the credit at the bottom of Simon's page that references this Q&A. I contacted Simon thinking he might be interested in this information. There are other commands on SS64 where I contributed info, and Simon is always good about providing credit. Likewise, I try to give credit when I post info that I had read elsewhere that is not already "common knowledge".

Comment: @dbenham , I think missed reading where Simon credits you for the source. There was/is no intentions of discredit. **Intention was/is to get link attached here for quick reference, as it was not listed earlier.** It just happened that google search results came up with these two link separately [link1](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman).
_Suggestion to include that link below the question with some highlighting for quick reference_.

Comment: `echo\"%temp%\."|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe [a-Z-0-9--]` works, but add "_", stack `echo\"%temp%\."|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe [a-Z-0-9--_]`

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe - Not sure what your point is. I haven't tested, but I think your first set should be interpreted as range `a-Z`, or character `-`, or range `0-9`, or character `-`, or character `-`. Which is the same as `[-a-Z0-9]`. Your last set simply adds `_` to the set.

Comment: I just found out that `findstr` terribly handles file names with leading `-` even when they are quoted, except they appear at a position where no more options are accepted; so `findstr "search expression" "-file name.ext"` is fine, but ``findstr /C:"search expression" "-file name.ext"`` is not, because all the characters in quotes behind `-` are attempted to be interpreted as options, some of which are illegal, and the file name argument is considered to be missing…

Comment: @aschipfl - good find. Probably the easiest work around is to prefix the file name with dot backslash,, as in `".\-file name.ext"`

Comment: @aschipfl - Added a note and solution to the Option Syntax section of the 1st answer

Comment: @HarryJohnston in Nov 2012: The URL for the historical context of the findstr command (Raymond Chen's *Old New Thing* blog) has changed to the new `devblogs` scheme: [Why are there both FIND and FINDSTR programs, with unrelated feature sets?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121128-00/?p=5963) • The [old URL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/11/28/10372436.aspx) is now HTTP 403. • By the way, good read as always with Raymond Chen. And very succinct. Parallel evolution.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

***Preface***
*Much of the information in this answer has been gathered based on experiments run on a Vista machine. Unless explicitly stated otherwise, I have not confirmed whether the information applies to other Windows versions.*

**FINDSTR output**
The documentation never bothers to explain the output of FINDSTR. It alludes to the fact that matching lines are printed, but nothing more.

The format of matching line output is as follows:

***filename:lineNumber:lineOffset:text***

where

***fileName:*** = The name of the file containing the matching line. The file name is not printed if the request was explicitly for a single file, or if searching piped input or redirected input. When printed, the fileName will always include any path information provided. Additional path information will be added if the `/S` option is used. The printed path is always relative to the provided path, or relative to the current directory if none provided.

Note - The filename prefix can be avoided when searching multiple files by using the [non-standard (and poorly documented) wildcards](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6207) `<` and `>`. The exact rules for how these wildcards work can be found [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=39420#p39420). Finally, you can look at this [example of how the non-standard wildcards work with FINDSTR](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6207&start=15).

***lineNumber:*** = The line number of the matching line represented as a decimal value with 1 representing the 1st line of the input. Only printed if `/N` option is specified.

***lineOffset:*** = The decimal byte offset of the start of the matching line, with 0 representing the 1st character of the 1st line. Only printed if `/O` option is specified. This is *not* the offset of the match within the line. It is the number of bytes from the beginning of the file to the beginning of the line.

***text*** = The binary representation of the matching line, including any <CR> and/or <LF>. Nothing is left out of the binary output, such that this example that matches all lines will produce an exact binary copy of the original file.

```
FINDSTR "^" FILE >FILE_COPY
```

**The /A option sets the color of the fileName:, lineNumber:, and lineOffset: output only.** The text of the matching line is always output with the current console color. The /A option only has effect when output is displayed directly to the console. The /A option has no effect if the output is redirected to a file or piped. See the [2018-08-18 edit in Aacini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28278628/1012053) for a description of the buggy behavior when output is redirected to CON.

**Most control characters and many extended ASCII characters display as dots on XP**
FINDSTR on XP displays most non-printable control characters from matching lines as dots (periods) on the screen. The following control characters are exceptions; they display as themselves: 0x09 Tab, 0x0A LineFeed, 0x0B Vertical Tab, 0x0C Form Feed, 0x0D Carriage Return.

XP FINDSTR also converts a number of extended ASCII characters to dots as well. The extended ASCII characters that display as dots on XP are the same as those that are transformed when supplied on the command line. See the *"Character limits for command line parameters - Extended ASCII transformation"* section, later in this post

Control characters and extended ASCII are not converted to dots on XP if the output is piped, redirected to a file, or within a FOR IN() clause.

Vista and Windows 7 always display all characters as themselves, never as dots.

**Return Codes (ERRORLEVEL)**

- 0 (success)

  - Match was found in at least one line of at least one file.
- 1 (failure)

  - No match was found in any line of any file.
  - Invalid color specified by `/A:xx` option
- 2 (error)

  - Incompatible options `/L` and `/R` both specified
  - Missing argument after `/A:`, `/F:`, `/C:`, `/D:`, or `/G:`
  - File specified by `/F:file` or `/G:file` not found
- 255 (error)

  - Too many regular expression character class terms
    *[see **Regex character class term limit and BUG** in part 2 of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159191/1012053)*

**Source of data to search** *(Updated based on tests with Windows 7)*
Findstr can search data from only one of the following sources:

- filenames specified as arguments and/or using the `/F:file` option.
- stdin via redirection `findstr "searchString" <file`
- data stream from a pipe `type file | findstr "searchString"`

Arguments/options take precedence over redirection, which takes precedence over piped data.

File name arguments and `/F:file` may be combined. Multiple file name arguments may be used. If multiple `/F:file` options are specified, then only the last one is used. Wild cards are allowed in filename arguments, but not within the file pointed to by `/F:file`.

**Source of search strings** *(Updated based on tests with Windows 7)*
The `/G:file` and `/C:string` options may be combined. Multiple `/C:string` options may be specified. If multiple `/G:file` options are specified, then only the last one is used. If either `/G:file` or `/C:string` is used, then all non-option arguments are assumed to be files to search. If neither `/G:file` nor `/C:string` is used, then the first non-option argument is treated as a space delimited list of search terms.

**File names must not be quoted within the file when using the `/F:FILE` option.**
File names may contain spaces and other special characters. Most commands require that such file names are quoted. But the FINDSTR `/F:files.txt` option requires that filenames within files.txt must NOT be quoted. The file will not be found if the name is quoted.

**BUG - Short 8.3 filenames can break the `/D` and `/S` options**
As with all Windows commands, FINDSTR will attempt to match both the long name and the short 8.3 name when looking for files to search. Assume the current folder contains the following non-empty files:

```
b1.txt
b.txt2
c.txt
```

The following command will successfully find all 3 files:

```
findstr /m "^" *.txt
```

`b.txt2` matches because the corresponding short name `B9F64~1.TXT` matches. This is consistent with the behavior of all other Windows commands.

But a bug with the `/D` and `/S` options causes the following commands to only find `b1.txt`

```
findstr /m /d:. "^" *.txt
findstr /m /s "^" *.txt
```

The bug prevents `b.txt2` from being found, as well as all file names that sort after `b.txt2` within the same directory. Additional files that sort before, like `a.txt`, are found. Additional files that sort later, like `d.txt`, are missed once the bug has been triggered.

Each directory searched is treated independently. For example, the `/S` option would successfully begin searching in a child folder after failing to find files in the parent, but once the bug causes a short file name to be missed in the child, then all subsequent files in that child folder would also be missed.

The commands work bug free if the same file names are created on a machine that has NTFS 8.3 name generation disabled. Of course `b.txt2` would not be found, but `c.txt` would be found properly.

Not all short names trigger the bug. All instances of bugged behavior I have seen involve an extension that is longer than 3 characters with a short 8.3 name that begins the same as a normal name that does not require an 8.3 name.

The bug has been confirmed on XP, Vista, and Windows 7.

**Non-Printable characters and the `/P` option**
The `/P` option causes FINDSTR to skip any file that contains any of the following decimal byte codes:
0-7, 14-25, 27-31.

Put another way, the `/P` option will only skip files that contain non-printable control characters. Control characters are codes less than or equal to 31 (0x1F). FINDSTR treats the following control characters as printable:

```
 8  0x08  backspace
 9  0x09  horizontal tab
10  0x0A  line feed
11  0x0B  vertical tab
12  0x0C  form feed
13  0x0D  carriage return
26  0x1A  substitute (end of text)
```

All other control characters are treated as non-printable, the presence of which causes the `/P` option to skip the file.

**Piped and Redirected input may have `<CR><LF>` appended**
If the input is piped in and the last character of the stream is not `<LF>`, then FINDSTR will automatically append `<CR><LF>` to the input. This has been confirmed on XP, Vista and Windows 7. *(I used to think that the Windows pipe was responsible for modifying the input, but I have since discovered that FINDSTR is actually doing the modification.)*

The same is true for redirected input on Vista. If the last character of a file used as redirected input is not `<LF>`, then FINDSTR will automatically append `<CR><LF>` to the input. However, XP and Windows 7 do not alter redirected input.

**FINDSTR hangs on XP and Windows 7 if redirected input does not end with `<LF>`**
This is a nasty "feature" on XP and Windows 7. If the last character of a file used as redirected input does not end with `<LF>`, then FINDSTR will hang indefinitely once it reaches the end of the redirected file.

**Last line of Piped data may be ignored if it consists of a single character**
If the input is piped in and the last line consists of a single character that is not followed by `<LF>`, then FINDSTR completely ignores the last line.

Example - The first command with a single character and no `<LF>` fails to match, but the second command with 2 characters works fine, as does the third command that has one character with terminating newline.

```
> set /p "=x" <nul | findstr "^"

> set /p "=xx" <nul | findstr "^"
xx

> echo x| findstr "^"
x
```

Reported by DosTips user Sponge Belly at [new findstr bug](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4669). Confirmed on XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8. Haven't heard about Vista yet. (I no longer have Vista to test).

**Option syntax**
Option letters are not case sensitive, so `/i` and `/I` are equivalent.

Options can be prefixed with either `/` or `-`
Options may be concatenated after a single `/` or `-`. However, the concatenated option list may contain at most one multicharacter option such as OFF or F:, and the multi-character option must be the last option in the list.

The following are all equivalent ways of expressing a case insensitive regex search for any line that contains both "hello" and "goodbye" in any order

- `/i /r /c:"hello.*goodbye" /c:"goodbye.*hello"`
- `-i -r -c:"hello.*goodbye" /c:"goodbye.*hello"`
- `/irc:"hello.*goodbye" /c:"goodbye.*hello"`

Options may also be quoted. So `/i`, `-i`, `"/i"` and `"-i"` are all equivalent. Likewise, `/c:string`, `"/c":string`, `"/c:"string` and `"/c:string"` are all equivalent.

If a search string begins with a `/` or `-` literal, then the `/C` or `/G` option must be used. Thanks to [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) for reporting this in a comment (since deleted).

If the `/c:string` or `/g:file` option is used, then the command will fail if the file name argument begins with `-`, even if quoted. This is because there is no search string argument, so the file name argument is then treated as an option. The easiest workaround is to prefix the file argument with dot backslash, as in

```
findstr /c:"searchString" ".\-fileName.txt"
```

**Search String length limits**
On Vista the maximum allowed length for a single search string is 511 bytes. If any search string exceeds 511 then the result is a `FINDSTR: Search string too long.` error with ERRORLEVEL 2.

When doing a regular expression search, the maximum search string length is 254. A regular expression with length between 255 and 511 will result in a `FINDSTR: Out of memory` error with ERRORLEVEL 2. A regular expression length >511 results in the `FINDSTR: Search string too long.` error.

On Windows XP the search string length is apparently shorter. [Findstr error: "Search string too long": How to extract and match substring in "for" loop?](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.msdos.batch.nt/browse_thread/thread/9f7e951942da7155)
The XP limit is 127 bytes for both literal and regex searches.

**Line Length limits**
Files specified as a command line argument or via the /F:FILE option have no known line length limit. Searches were successfully run against a 128MB file that did not contain a single <LF>.

Piped data and Redirected input is limited to 8191 bytes per line. This limit is a "feature" of FINDSTR. It is not inherent to pipes or redirection. FINDSTR using redirected stdin or piped input will never match any line that is >=8k bytes. Lines >= 8k generate an error message to stderr, but ERRORLEVEL is still 0 if the search string is found in at least one line of at least one file.

**Default type of search: Literal vs Regular Expression**
`/C:"string"` - The default is /L literal. Explicitly combining the /L option with /C:"string" certainly works but is redundant.

`"string argument"` - The default depends on the content of the very first search string. *(Remember that <space> is used to delimit search strings.)* If the first search string is a valid regular expression that contains at least one un-escaped meta-character, then all search strings are treated as regular expressions. Otherwise all search strings are treated as literals. For example, `"51.4 200"` will be treated as two regular expressions because the first string contains an un-escaped dot, whereas `"200 51.4"` will be treated as two literals because the first string does not contain any meta-characters.

`/G:file` - The default depends on the content of the first non-empty line in the file. If the first search string is a valid regular expression that contains at least one un-escaped meta-character, then all search strings are treated as regular expressions. Otherwise all search strings are treated as literals.

*Recommendation - Always explicitly specify `/L` literal option or `/R` regular expression option when using `"string argument"` or `/G:file`.*

**BUG - Specifying multiple literal search strings can give unreliable results**

The following simple FINDSTR example fails to find a match, even though it should.

```
echo ffffaaa|findstr /l "ffffaaa faffaffddd"
```

This bug has been confirmed on Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Vista, and Windows 7.

Based on experiments, FINDSTR may fail if all of the following conditions are met:

- The search is using multiple literal search strings
- The search strings are of different lengths
- A short search string has some amount of overlap with a longer search string
- The search is case sensitive (no `/I` option)

In every failure I have seen, it is always one of the shorter search strings that fails.

For more info see [Why doesn't this FINDSTR example with multiple literal search strings find a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921253/why-doesnt-this-findstr-example-with-multiple-literal-search-strings-find-a-mat/8921279#8921279)

> ***Quotes and backslahses within command line arguments***
> ***Note -*** *User MC ND's comments reflect the actual horrifically complicated rules for this section. There are 3 distinct parsing phases involved:*
>
> - *First cmd.exe may require some quotes to be escaped as ^" (really nothing to do with FINDSTR)*
> - *Next FINDSTR uses the [pre 2008 MS C/C++ argument parser](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULES), which has special rules for " and \*
> - *After the argument parser finishes, FINDSTR additionally treats \ followed by an alpha-numeric character as literal, but \ followed by non-alpha-numeric character as an escape character*
>
> *The remainder of this highlighted section is not 100% correct. It can serve as a guide for many situations, but the above rules are required for total understanding.*
>
> **Escaping Quote within command line search strings**
>  Quotes within command line search strings must be escaped with backslash like
> `\"`. This is true for both literal and regex search strings. This
> information has been confirmed on XP, Vista, and Windows 7.
>
> *Note: The quote may also need to be escaped for the CMD.EXE parser, but this has nothing to do with FINDSTR. For example, to search for a
> single quote you could use:*
>
> `FINDSTR \^" file && echo found || echo not found`
>
> **Escaping Backslash within command line literal search strings**
>  Backslash in a literal search string can normally be represented as
> `\` or as `\\`. They are typically equivalent. *(There may be unusual
> cases in Vista where the backslash must always be escaped, but I no
> longer have a Vista machine to test)*.
>
> But there are some special cases:
>
> When searching for consecutive backslashes, all but the last *must* be
> escaped. The last backslash may optionally be escaped.
>
> - `\\` can be coded as `\\\` or `\\\\`
> - `\\\` can be coded as `\\\\\` or `\\\\\\`
>
> Searching for one or more backslashes before a quote is bizarre. Logic
> would suggest that the quote must be escaped, and each of the leading
> backslashes would need to be escaped, but this does not work! Instead,
> each of the leading backslashes must be double escaped, and the quote
> is escaped normally:
>
> - `\"` must be coded as `\\\\\"`
> - `\\"` must be coded as `\\\\\\\\\"`
>
> *As previously noted, one or more escaped quotes may also require escaping with `^` for the CMD parser*
>
> The info in this section has been confirmed on XP and Windows 7.
>
> **Escaping Backslash within command line regex search strings**
>
> - **Vista only:** Backslash in a regex must be either double escaped like `\\\\`, or else single escaped within a character class set like
>   `[\\]`
> - **XP and Windows 7:** Backslash in a regex can always be represented as `[\\]`. It can normally be represented as `\\`. But this never
>   works if the backslash precedes an escaped quote.
>
>   One or more backslashes before an escaped quote must either be
>   double escaped, or else coded as `[\\]`
>
>   - `\"` may be coded as `\\\\\"` or `[\\]\"`
>   - `\\"` may be coded as `\\\\\\\\\"` or `[\\][\\]\"` or `\\[\\]\"`

**Escaping Quote and Backslash within /G:FILE literal search strings**
Standalone quotes and backslashes within a literal search string file specified by /G:file need not be escaped, but they can be.

`"` and `\"` are equivalent.

`\` and `\\` are equivalent.

If the intent is to find \\, then at least the leading backslash must be escaped. Both `\\\` and `\\\\` work.

If the intent is to find ", then at least the leading backslash must be escaped. Both `\\"` and `\\\"` work.

**Escaping Quote and Backslash within /G:FILE regex search strings**
This is the one case where the escape sequences work as expected based on the documentation. Quote is not a regex metacharacter, so it need not be escaped (but can be). Backslash is a regex metacharacter, so it must be escaped.

**Character limits for command line parameters - Extended ASCII transformation**
The null character (0x00) cannot appear in any string on the command line. Any other single byte character can appear in the string (0x01 - 0xFF). However, FINDSTR converts many extended ASCII characters it finds within command line parameters into other characters. This has a major impact in two ways:

1. Many extended ASCII characters will not match themselves if used as a search string on the command line. This limitation is the same for literal and regex searches. If a search string must contain extended ASCII, then the `/G:FILE` option should be used instead.
2. FINDSTR may fail to find a file if the name contains extended ASCII characters and the file name is specified on the command line. If a file to be searched contains extended ASCII in the name, then the `/F:FILE` option should be used instead.

Here is a complete list of extended ASCII character transformations that FINDSTR performs on command line strings. Each character is represented as the decimal byte code value. The first code represents the character as supplied on the command line, and the second code represents the character it is transformed into. *Note - this list was compiled on a U.S machine. I do not know what impact other languages may have on this list.*

```
158 treated as 080     199 treated as 221     226 treated as 071
169 treated as 170     200 treated as 043     227 treated as 112
176 treated as 221     201 treated as 043     228 treated as 083
177 treated as 221     202 treated as 045     229 treated as 115
178 treated as 221     203 treated as 045     231 treated as 116
179 treated as 221     204 treated as 221     232 treated as 070
180 treated as 221     205 treated as 045     233 treated as 084
181 treated as 221     206 treated as 043     234 treated as 079
182 treated as 221     207 treated as 045     235 treated as 100
183 treated as 043     208 treated as 045     236 treated as 056
184 treated as 043     209 treated as 045     237 treated as 102
185 treated as 221     210 treated as 045     238 treated as 101
186 treated as 221     211 treated as 043     239 treated as 110
187 treated as 043     212 treated as 043     240 treated as 061
188 treated as 043     213 treated as 043     242 treated as 061
189 treated as 043     214 treated as 043     243 treated as 061
190 treated as 043     215 treated as 043     244 treated as 040
191 treated as 043     216 treated as 043     245 treated as 041
192 treated as 043     217 treated as 043     247 treated as 126
193 treated as 045     218 treated as 043     249 treated as 250
194 treated as 045     219 treated as 221     251 treated as 118
195 treated as 043     220 treated as 095     252 treated as 110
196 treated as 045     222 treated as 221     254 treated as 221
197 treated as 043     223 treated as 095
198 treated as 221     224 treated as 097
```

Any character >0 not in the list above is treated as itself, including `<CR>` and <`LF>`. The easiest way to include odd characters like `<CR>` and `<LF>` is to get them into an environment variable and use delayed expansion within the command line argument.

**Character limits for strings found in files specified by /G:FILE and /F:FILE options**
The nul (0x00) character can appear in the file, but it functions like the C string terminator. Any characters after a nul character are treated as a different string as if they were on another line.

The `<CR>` and `<LF>` characters are treated as line terminators that terminate a string, and are not included in the string.

All other single byte characters are included perfectly within a string.

***Searching Unicode files***
*FINDSTR cannot properly search most Unicode (UTF-16, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32) because it cannot search for nul bytes and Unicode typically contains many nul bytes.*

*However, the TYPE command converts UTF-16LE with BOM to a single byte character set, so a command like the following will work with UTF-16LE with BOM.*

```
type unicode.txt|findstr "search"
```

*Note that Unicode code points that are not supported by your active code page will be converted to `?` characters.*

*It is possible to search UTF-8 as long as your search string contains only ASCII. However, the console output of any multi-byte UTF-8 characters will not be correct. But if you redirect the output to a file, then the result will be correctly encoded UTF-8. Note that if the UTF-8 file contains a BOM, then the BOM will be considered as part of the first line, which could throw off a search that matches the beginning of a line.*

*It is possible to search multi-byte UTF-8 characters if you put your search string in a UTF-8 encoded search file (without BOM), and use the /G option.*

**End Of Line**
FINDSTR breaks lines immediately after every <LF>. The presence or absence of <CR> has no impact on line breaks.

**Searching across line breaks**
As expected, the `.` regex metacharacter will not  match <CR> or <LF>. But it is possible to search across a line break using a command line search string. Both the <CR> and <LF> characters must be matched explicitly. If a multi-line match is found, only the 1st line of the match is printed. FINDSTR then doubles back to the 2nd line in the source and begins the search all over again - sort of a "look ahead" type feature.

Assume TEXT.TXT has these contents (could be Unix or Windows style)

```
A
A
A
B
A
A
```

Then this script

```
@echo off
setlocal
::Define LF variable containing a linefeed (0x0A)
set LF=^


::Above 2 blank lines are critical - do not remove

::Define CR variable containing a carriage return (0x0D)
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
::regex "!CR!*!LF!" will match both Unix and Windows style End-Of-Line
findstr /n /r /c:"A!CR!*!LF!A" TEST.TXT
```

gives these results

```
1:A
2:A
5:A
```

Searching across line breaks using the /G:FILE option is imprecise because the only way to match <CR> or <LF> is via a regex character class range expression that sandwiches the EOL characters.

- `[<TAB>-<0x0B>]` matches <LF>, but it also matches <TAB> and <0x0B>
- `[<0x0C>-!]` matches <CR>, but it also matches <0x0C> and !

*Note - the above are symbolic representations of the regex byte stream since I can't graphically represent the characters.*

*[Answer continued in part 2 below...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159191/1012053)*

Comment: Outstanding completeness.  If only all answers on the internet were like this.

Comment: we've encountered a problem with `addpath.bat` from [Q141344](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141344/) and findstr, which may be related to the Win7 hanging problem mentioned above. I've created a chat room to try and track this down, for anyone who's interested: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13177/addpath-bat-and-findstr-troubles

Comment: EDIT - Described display of control characters as dots on XP. Also documented bugged `/S` and `/D` options stemming from short 8.3 file names.

Comment: EDIT - 1) File names within file specified by /F:FILE must not be quoted. 2) Transformation of extended ASCII characters affects both search strings and file names when supplied on the command line.

Comment: thanks a lot for the great article! maybe you could help me with a findstr expression problem. i want to find a string that contains the ">" and "<"(greater than) character. i tried to escape it with ^ or \. also using character codes in a syntax like <0x3C> and [<0x3C>] but no success so far. any ideas?

Comment: @weberik - You should post a question showing what you want your search string to be (logical, not necessarily valid FINDSTR syntax), plus what strings should match. It would also help if you post some example code attempts that failed, and how they failed.

Comment: actually my question here is the result from another question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232263/batch-code-to-chnage-folders-name-after-read-text-files/14232658 maybe you could take a look at it? the main problem is as far as i understand a findstr expression that matches tags(similar to xml)

Comment: EDIT - Added bug where last line of piped input is ignored if it consists of a single character without `<LF>`

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful! Apart from the multiple search string bug (which I could not reproduce on Vista-X64 using the example you gave), do you know more about the limits of multiple search strings? I have used the /g to specify up to 10000 search strings (apparently successfully, but I'm hardly likely to manually check the results!).

Comment: EDIT - Reworked escape rules for backslashes on the command line.

Comment: EDIT - Added documentation describing how non-standard wildcards `<` and `>` avoid the filename prefix in FINDSTR output.

Comment: a limitation of the `/A:attr` for coloring the filename, is that colors are stripped if piped to another command.

Comment: Concerning word boundaries: you say that `\<` and `\>` must be the *first* and *last* term in the *regex*, but something like `findstr "\<word1\> \<word2\>"` seems to work fine as well (@ Win7); would you please clarify? (I consider the entire string in between `""` as the regex containing two search strings -- does that comply with your interpretation?)

Comment: @aschipfl - Your example has two independent regex expressions within one parameter. My word boundary rule applies to each individual regex expression, not the parameter as a whole.

Comment: Just for information (I don't know if you already know it, but I see no mention in your answer). The reason of most of the *"bizarre"* backslash+quotes rules is that `findstr` is an `exe` file, and [some rules](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WIN) control how backslashes+quotes are handled by the argument tokenizer, but once the arguments are parsed, the `findstr` code has a *string* that needs to be compiled into a *regular expression* instance. So, some backslashes are interpreted twice.

Comment: A literal backslash does not need any escape (`findstr /l \ *.cmd`), but a double quoted literal backslash needs it (`findstr /l "\\" *.cmd`) to avoid the escaped quote. BUT the `findstr` string parser will handle a literal backslash followed by a *non alphanumeric character* (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`) as a escape character : `findstr /l /c:"\ o" *.cmd` searchs a space followed by a  `o` character as the backslash escapes the space, but `findstr /l /c:"\w" *.cmd` searchs a backslash followed by a `w` character (it is alphanumeric, so it is not escaped)

Comment: @MCND - Whoa, great link, thanks! I believe it explains literal FINDSTR searches. I still have a few regex searches that don't make sense to me yet. The path to understanding is very long and narrow, with a 100 meter drop off on either side. I've already fallen several times, and my head hurts! I'll study some more, and try to amend my answer. Either way, I'll definitely add your link to my answer, with credit.

Comment: @MCND - Oooh, I've never seen that literal search rule of backslash before non-alpha as **always** being an escape. Nice find. Feel free to add your own answer if you want, including your link, and I will definitely upvote. Or if you prefer, I'll add it to my answer. What OS are you using?

Comment: @dbenham, I think it is easier to find the information if it is grouped, please add it to your answer, thank you. I'm using W7 32b and W10 64b, both profesional version spanish locale.

Comment: EDIT - Refined the **Return Code** section, and moved the regex discussion to part 2.

Comment: EDIT - I finally amended the section on command line argument backslash and quote rules to include MC ND's C/C++ link.

Comment: @dbenham, wondering if there should be a short blurb about the `/A:` option? The `FINDSTR` help does not specify that only the file name will be color coded when searching multiple files. One could infer from reading the help for the very first time that it could change the color of the string found in the output. I guess it technically isn't an undocumented feature or limitation but it certainly seems odd that Microsoft doesn't specifically point this out.  The documentation on **SS64** does.

Comment: @Squashman - I finally made your recommended update :-)

Comment: "Any other single byte character can appear in the string (0x01 - 0xFF)" - 0x80-0xFF aren't single-byte characters (most of them are lead/continuation bytes of multibyte characters, and some can't appear at all).

Comment: @Vikki - That all depends on the encoding of the source file. But FINDSTR is not aware of multibyte characters, and treats each byte as a character unto itself.

Comment: @dbenham: Yeesh, how old is FINDSTR?!

Answer (score 76):

*[Answer continued from part 1 above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/1012053) - I've run into the 30,000 character answer limit :-(*

**Limited Regular Expressions (regex) Support**
FINDSTR support for regular expressions is extremely limited. If it is not in the HELP documentation, it is not supported.

Beyond that, the regex expressions that are supported are implemented in a completely non-standard manner, such that results can be different then would be expected coming from something like grep or perl.

**Regex Line Position anchors ^ and $**
`^` matches beginning of input stream as well as any position immediately following a <LF>. Since FINDSTR also breaks lines after <LF>, a simple regex of "^" will always match all lines within a file, even a binary file.

`$` matches any position immediately preceding a <CR>. This means that a regex search string containing `$` will never match any lines within a Unix style text file, nor will it match the last line of a Windows text file if it is missing the EOL marker of <CR><LF>.

*Note - As previously discussed, piped and redirected input to FINDSTR may have `<CR><LF>` appended that is not in the source. Obviously this can impact a regex search that uses `$`.*

Any search string with characters before `^` or after `$` will always fail to find a match.

**Positional Options /B /E /X**
The positional options work the same as `^` and `$`, except they also work for literal search strings.

/B functions the same as `^` at the start of a regex search string.

/E functions the same as `$` at the end of a regex search string.

/X functions the same as having both `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end of a regex search string.

**Regex word boundary**
`\<` must be the very first term in the regex. The regex will not match anything if any other characters precede it. `\<` corresponds to either the very beginning of the input, the beginning of a line (the position immediately following a <LF>), or the position immediately following any "non-word" character. The next character need not be a "word" character.

`\>` must be the very last term in the regex. The regex will not match anything if any other characters follow it. `\>` corresponds to either the end of input, the position immediately prior to a <CR>, or the position immediately preceding any "non-word" character. The preceding character need not be a "word" character.

Here is a complete list of "non-word" characters, represented as the decimal byte code. *Note - this list was compiled on a U.S machine. I do not know what impact other languages may have on this list.*

```
001   028   063   179   204   230
002   029   064   180   205   231
003   030   091   181   206   232
004   031   092   182   207   233
005   032   093   183   208   234
006   033   094   184   209   235
007   034   096   185   210   236
008   035   123   186   211   237
009   036   124   187   212   238
011   037   125   188   213   239
012   038   126   189   214   240
014   039   127   190   215   241
015   040   155   191   216   242
016   041   156   192   217   243
017   042   157   193   218   244
018   043   158   194   219   245
019   044   168   195   220   246
020   045   169   196   221   247
021   046   170   197   222   248
022   047   173   198   223   249
023   058   174   199   224   250
024   059   175   200   226   251
025   060   176   201   227   254
026   061   177   202   228   255
027   062   178   203   229
```

**Regex character class ranges [x-y]**
Character class ranges do not work as expected. See this question: [Why does findstr not handle case properly (in some circumstances)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635740/why-does-findstr-not-handle-case-properly-in-some-circumstances), along with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767815/1012053.

The problem is FINDSTR does not collate the characters by their byte code value (commonly thought of as the ASCII code, but ASCII is only defined from 0x00 - 0x7F). Most regex implementations would treat [A-Z] as all upper case English capital letters. But FINDSTR uses a collation sequence that roughly corresponds to how SORT works. So [A-Z] includes the complete English alphabet, both upper and lower case (except for "a"), as well as non-English alpha characters with diacriticals.

Below is a complete list of all characters supported by FINDSTR, sorted in the collation sequence used by FINDSTR to establish regex character class ranges. The characters are represented as their decimal byte code value. I believe the collation sequence makes the most sense if the characters are viewed using code page 437. *Note - this list was compiled on a U.S machine. I do not know what impact other languages may have on this list.*

```
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
014
015
016
017
018           
019
020
021
022
023
024
025
026
027
028
029
030
031
127
039
045
032
255
009
010
011
012
013
033
034
035
036
037
038
040
041
042
044
046
047
058
059
063
064
091
092
093
094
095
096
123
124
125
126
173
168
155
156
157
158
043
249
060
061
062
241
174
175
246
251
239
247
240
243
242
169
244
245
254
196
205
179
186
218
213
214
201
191
184
183
187
192
212
211
200
217
190
189
188
195
198
199
204
180
181
182
185
194
209
210
203
193
207
208
202
197
216
215
206
223
220
221
222
219
176
177
178
170
248
230
250
048
172
171
049
050
253
051
052
053
054
055
056
057
236
097
065
166
160
133
131
132
142
134
143
145
146
098
066
099
067
135
128
100
068
101
069
130
144
138
136
137
102
070
159
103
071
104
072
105
073
161
141
140
139
106
074
107
075
108
076
109
077
110
252
078
164
165
111
079
167
162
149
147
148
153
112
080
113
081
114
082
115
083
225
116
084
117
085
163
151
150
129
154
118
086
119
087
120
088
121
089
152
122
090
224
226
235
238
233
227
229
228
231
237
232
234
```

**Regex character class term limit and BUG**
Not only is FINDSTR limited to a maximum of 15 character class terms within a regex, it fails to properly handle an attempt to exceed the limit. Using 16 or more character class terms results in an interactive Windows pop up stating *"Find String (QGREP) Utility has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience."* The message text varies slightly depending on the Windows version. Here is one example of a FINDSTR that will fail:

```
echo 01234567890123456|findstr [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

This bug was reported by DosTips user Judago [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=12935#p12935). It has been confirmed on XP, Vista, and Windows 7.

**Regex searches fail (and may hang indefinitely) if they include byte code 0xFF (decimal 255)**
Any regex search that includes byte code 0xFF (decimal 255) will fail. It fails if byte code 0xFF is included directly, or if it is implicitly included within a character class range. Remember that FINDSTR character class ranges do not collate characters based on the byte code value. Character `<0xFF>` appears relatively early in the collation sequence between the `<space>` and `<tab>` characters. So any character class range that includes both `<space>` and `<tab>` will fail.

The exact behavior changes slightly depending on the Windows version. Windows 7 hangs indefinitely if 0xFF is included. XP doesn't hang, but it always fails to find a match, and occasionally prints the following error message - *"The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe."*

I no longer have access to a Vista machine, so I haven't been able to test on Vista.

**Regex bug: `.` and `[^anySet]` can match End-Of-File**
The regex `.` meta-character should only match any character other than `<CR>` or `<LF>`. There is a bug that allows it to match the End-Of-File if the last line in the file is not terminated by `<CR>` or `<LF>`. However, the `.` will not match an empty file.

For example, a file named "test.txt" containing a single line of `x`, without terminating `<CR>` or `<LF>`, will match the following:

```
findstr /r x......... test.txt
```

This bug has been confirmed on XP and Win7.

The same seems to be true for negative character sets. Something like `[^abc]` will match End-Of-File. Positive character sets like `[abc]` seem to work fine. I have only tested this on Win7.

Comment: findstr is also buggy dealing with large files. Files > 2GB can cause findstr to hang. It doens't always happen. In confirming the bug I searched a file that was 2.3GB which didn't hang. It hangs even if searching only a single file. Workaround is to pipe the output of `type` into `findstr`.

Comment: It's probably also worthwhile explcitly mentioning that `findstr` supports multiple `/c:` search strings. I know your answers do demonstrate this. But it is something that is not documented; and I was quite surprised to learn of the feature after having used `findstr` without it for a few years.

Comment: @CraigYoung - You are right about the search string sources. I edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: No. As mentioned in my comment, redirecting output using `type` **works** as a workaround. Alos, all lines end in CRLF. I'll post a session as an answer, and you can try it for yourself. Perhaps you'll notice something else that could be causing the problem.

Comment: @CraigYoung - But FINDSTR will automatically append `<CR><LF>` to any piped input if the last line does not end with `<LF>`. So I would expect it to work if you pipe the result of TYPE to FINDSTR. It should also work if you let FINDSTR open the file directly with a filename as an argument. It can hang if you use redirection (not a pipe) and the last line does not contain `<LF>`. If this does not explain things, then open a new question, showing the exact commands you use, and include a link to something like DropBox containing the large file. P.S. I had no problem with a 2.9GB file.

Comment: On further investigation, it looks like a variation on the `LF` issue you documented. I realised my test file didn't end in `LF` because I used `copy` in append mode to create it. I've put a command line session to demonstrate the issue into an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22943056/224704). Note that input is **not** redirected, and yet the search hangs. The exact same search command **doesn't hang** with a smaller files that similarly don't end with `LF`.

Comment: I did not even know there was a character limit

Comment: New finding (Win7): `findstr /R /C:"^[0-9][0-9]* [0-3][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]* [0-9]*\.[0-9]*"` (15 character classes) -- `ErrorLevel = -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`, **error dialog window**: `Find String (QGREP) Utility has stopped working`; after removing one class or two meta characters (`*\.`), it works...

Comment: I was trying on Windows 10 to match all but the last line of a file independent on whether or not it is terminated by a final line-break using `findstr "!LF!. !LF!!CR!*!LF!" "file.txt"` (the second search string is just to return blank lines too), but I was failing because of the stated issue that `.` can match the end-of-file. The only chance to get the desired result was this work-around: `> nul findstr /V "$" "file.txt" && (findstr "$" "file.txt") || (findstr "!LF!.*!CR!!LF!" "file.txt")` (with delayed exp. and `!LF!` and `!CR!` representing the resp. chars.; only for Windows-style files!)…

Answer (score 9):

`findstr` sometimes hangs unexpectedly when searching large files.

I haven't confirmed the exact conditions or boundary sizes. I suspect any file larger 2GB may be at risk.

I have had mixed experiences with this, so it is more than just file size. This looks like it may be a variation on [FINDSTR hangs on XP and Windows 7 if redirected input does not end with LF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/224704), but as demonstrated this particular problem manifests when input is **not** redirected.

The following command line session (Windows 7) demonstrates how `findstr` can hang when searching a 3GB file.

```
C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>echo 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890> T100B.txt

C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>for /L %i in (1,1,10) do @type T100B.txt >> T1KB.txt

C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>for /L %i in (1,1,1000) do @type T1KB.txt >> T1MB.txt

C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>for /L %i in (1,1,1000) do @type T1MB.txt >> T1GB.txt

C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>echo find this line>> T1GB.txt

C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>copy T1GB.txt + T1GB.txt + T1GB.txt T3GB.txt
T1GB.txt
T1GB.txt
T1GB.txt
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is D2B2-FFDF

 Directory of C:\Data\Temp\2014-04

2014/04/08  04:28 PM    <DIR>          .
2014/04/08  04:28 PM    <DIR>          ..
2014/04/08  04:22 PM               102 T100B.txt
2014/04/08  04:28 PM     1 020 000 016 T1GB.txt
2014/04/08  04:23 PM             1 020 T1KB.txt
2014/04/08  04:23 PM         1 020 000 T1MB.txt
2014/04/08  04:29 PM     3 060 000 049 T3GB.txt
               5 File(s)  4 081 021 187 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  51 881 050 112 bytes free
C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>rem Findstr on the 1GB file does not hang

C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>findstr "this" T1GB.txt
find this line

C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>rem On the 3GB file, findstr hangs and must be aborted... even though it clearly reaches end of file

C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>findstr "this" T3GB.txt
find this line
find this line
find this line
^C
C:\Data\Temp\2014-04>
```

Note, I've verified in a hex editor that all lines are terminated with `CRLF`. The only anomaly is that the file is terminated with `0x1A` due to [the way `copy` works](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040316-00/?p=40233/). Note however, that this anomaly ***doesn't cause a problem on "small" files***.

With additional testing I have confirmed the following:

- Using `copy` with the `/b` option for binary files prevents the addition of the `0x1A` character, and `findstr` doesn't hang on the 3GB file.
- Terminating the 3GB file with a different character also causes a `findstr` to hang.
- The `0x1A` character doesn't cause any problems on a "small" file. (Similarly for other terminating characters.)
- Adding `CRLF` after `0x1A` resolves the problem. (`LF` by itself would probably suffice.)
- Using `type` to pipe the file into `findstr` works without hanging. (This might be due to a side effect of either `type` or `|` that inserts an additional End Of Line.)
- Use redirected input `<` also causes `findstr` to hang. *But this is expected; as explained in [dbenham's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/224704): "redirected input must end in `LF`"*.

Comment: +1, I am able to confirm the problem on my Win7 machine. A file exactly 2GiB in size hung when the last character was not `<LF>`. A file two bytes smaller did not hang. Very nasty!

Answer (score 9):

When several commands are enclosed in parentheses and there are redirected files to the whole block:

```
< input.txt (
   command1
   command2
   . . .
) > output.txt
```

... then the files remains open as long as the commands in the block be active, so the commands may move the file pointer of the redirected files. Both MORE and FIND commands move the Stdin file pointer to the beginning of the file before process it, so the same file may be processed several times inside the block. For example, this code:

```
more < input.txt >  output.txt
more < input.txt >> output.txt
```

... produce the same result than this one:

```
< input.txt (
   more
   more
) > output.txt
```

This code:

```
find    "search string" < input.txt > matchedLines.txt
find /V "search string" < input.txt > unmatchedLines.txt
```

... produce the same result than this one:

```
< input.txt (
   find    "search string" > matchedLines.txt
   find /V "search string" > unmatchedLines.txt
)
```

FINDSTR is different; it does *not* move the Stdin file pointer from its current position. For example, this code insert a new line after a search line:

```
call :ProcessFile < input.txt
goto :EOF

:ProcessFile
   rem Read the next line from Stdin and copy it
   set /P line=
   echo %line%
   rem Test if it is the search line
   if "%line%" neq "search line" goto ProcessFile
rem Insert the new line at this point
echo New line
rem And copy the rest of lines
findstr "^"
exit /B
```

We may make good use of this feature with the aid of an auxiliary program that allow us to move the file pointer of a redirected file, as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199370/batch-insert-element-from-xml-with-shared-filename/28206441#28206441).

This behavior was first reported by [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2128&p=9720#p9720).

---

**EDIT 2018-08-18**: *New FINDSTR bug reported*

The FINDSTR command have a strange bug that happen when this command is used to show characters in color AND the output of such a command is redirected to CON device. For details on how use FINDSTR command to show text in color, see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file#5344911).

When the output of this form of FINDSTR command is redirected to CON, something strange happens after the text is output in the desired color: all the text after it is output as "invisible" characters, although a more precise description is that the text is output as black text over black background. The original text will appear if you use COLOR command to reset the foreground and background colors of the entire screen. However, when the text is "invisible" we could execute a SET /P command, so all characters entered will not appear on the screen. This behavior may be used to enter passwords.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /P "=_" < NUL > "Enter password"
findstr /A:1E /V "^$" "Enter password" NUL > CON
del "Enter password"
set /P "password="
cls
color 07
echo The password read is: "%password%"
```

Answer (score 3):

FINDSTR has a color bug that I described and solved at https://superuser.com/questions/1535810/is-there-a-better-way-to-mitigate-this-obscure-color-bug-when-piping-to-findstr/1538802?noredirect=1#comment2339443_1538802

To summarize that thread, the bug is that if input is piped to FINDSTR within a parenthesized block of code, inline ANSI escape colorcodes stop working in commands executed later. An example of inline colorcodes is: `echo %magenta%Alert: Something bad happened%yellow%` (where magenta and yellow are vars defined earlier in the .bat file as the corresponding ANSI escape colorcodes).

My initial solution was to call a do-nothing subroutine after the FINDSTR.  Somehow the call or the return "resets" whatever needs to be reset.

Later I discovered another solution that presumably is more efficient: place the FINDSTR phrase within parentheses, as in the following example:
`echo success | ( FINDSTR /R success )`
**Placing the FINDSTR phrase within a nested block of code appears to isolate FINDSTR's colorcode bug so it won't affect what's outside the nested block.  Perhaps this technique will solve some other undesired FINDSTR side effects too**.

Comment: Great find. But your rules can be simplified (at least on my enterprise Windows 10 machine). FINDSTR prevents all console escape sequences from working for subsequent commands within the same command block. It doesn't matter if FINDSTR reads a pipe, redirected input, or a file. The escape sequence failure is not restricted to color codes. A command block is any set of commands within parentheses, and/or commands concatenated via &, &&, or ||

Comment: @dbenham: Nice generalization of the problem.  Do you know whether my solution -- nesting the FINDSTR phrase inside parentheses -- works in the general case too?  And do you know whether my solution has any undesirable side effects?

Comment: I did not do any exhaustive testing, but yes, the nested parentheses seems to be a general solution, and I can't think of any possible undesirable side effects.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to report a bug regarding the section **Source of data to search** in the first answer when using *en dash* (–) or *em dash* (—) within the filename.

More specifically, if you are about to use the first option - *filenames specified as arguments*, the file won't be found. As soon as you use either option 2 - *stdin via redirection* or 3 - *data stream from a pipe*, findstr will find the file.

For example, this simple batch script:

```
echo off
chcp 1250 > nul
set INTEXTFILE1=filename with – dash.txt
set INTEXTFILE2=filename with — dash.txt

rem 3 way of findstr use with en dashed filename
echo.
echo Filename with en dash:
echo.
echo 1. As argument
findstr . "%INTEXTFILE1%"
echo.
echo 2. As stdin via redirection
findstr . < "%INTEXTFILE1%"
echo.
echo 3. As datastream from a pipe
type "%INTEXTFILE1%" | findstr .
echo.
echo.
rem The same set of operations with em dashed filename
echo Filename with em dash:
echo.
echo 1. As argument
findstr . "%INTEXTFILE2%"
echo.
echo 2. As stdin via redirection
findstr . < "%INTEXTFILE2%"
echo.
echo 3. As datastream from a pipe
type "%INTEXTFILE2%" | findstr .
echo.

pause
```

will print:

Filename with en dash:

1. As argument
   **FINDSTR: Cannot open filename with - dash.txt**
2. As stdin via redirection
   **I am the file with an en dash.**
3. As datastream from a pipe
   **I am the file with an en dash.**

Filename with em dash:

1. As argument
   **FINDSTR: Cannot open filename with - dash.txt**
2. As stdin via redirection
   **I am the file with an em dash.**
3. As datastream from a pipe
   **I am the file with an em dash.**

Hope it helps.

M.

Comment: Hi matro, while your comments may be correct, I'm not sure they don't address the actual question.

Comment: I believe this is a unicode issue, which FINDSTR does not support. CMD.EXE redirection can properly open a file name with unicode, as can the TYPE command. But somewhere along the line, FINDSTR converts both the en-dash and em-dash to a normal dash, and of course the OS cannot find that name. If you create another file substituting a dash for the en-dash and/or em-dash, then FINDSTR will search the dash file if provided with a name containing en-dash or em-dash.

Comment: I would classify this issue as a limitation rather than a bug.

Comment: Actually, this isn't so much a unicode issue as it is extended ASCII. I already documented this issue in my original answer under the heading **Character limits for command line parameters - Extended ASCII transformation**. FINDSTR transforms a number of extended ASCII codes into "related" true ASCII, including the en-dash and em-dash.

Answer (score 2):

The [`findstr` command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) sets the [`ErrorLevel` (or exit code)](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) to one of the following values, given that there are no invalid or incompatible switches and no search string exceeds the applicable length limit:

- `0` when at least a single match is encountered in one line throughout all specified files;
- `1` otherwise;

A line is considered to contain a match when:

- no `/V` option is given and the search expression occurs at least once;
- the `/V` option is given and the search expression does not occur;

This means that the `/V` option also changes the returned `ErrorLevel`, but it does **not** just revert it!

For example, when you have got a file `test.txt` with two lines, one of which contains the string `text` but the other one does not, both `findstr "text" "test.txt"` and `findstr /V "text" "test.txt"` return an `ErrorLevel` of `0`.

Basically you can say: if `findstr` returns at least a line, `ErrorLevel` is set to `0`, else to `1`.

Note that the `/M` option does not affect the `ErrorLevel` value, it just alters the output.

(Just for the sake of completeness: the [`find` command](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) behaves exactly the same way with respect to the `/V` option and `ErrorLevel`; the `/C` option does not affect `ErrorLevel`.)

Answer (score -1):

/D tip for multiple directories: put your directory list before the search string. These all work:

```
findstr /D:dir1;dir2 "searchString" *.*
findstr /D:"dir1;dir2" "searchString" *.*
findstr /D:"\path\dir1\;\path\dir2\" "searchString" *.*
```

As expected, the path is relative to location if you don't start the directories with `\`. Surrounding the path with `"` is optional if there are no spaces in the directory names. The ending `\` is optional. The output of location will include whatever path you give it. It will work with or without surrounding the directory list with `"`.

Comment: I don't see anything undocumented here. The /D option is described in the built in help. This is not a question for general tips on how to use FINDSTR. It is strictly intended to list undocumented features, limitations, and/or bugs.

Comment: @dbenham true it's not truly undocumented, but I found I had to dicker with findstr to get the results I wanted and am sharing what I found DID work so folks wouldn't waste time experimenting with commands that do NOT work. hth (I am sad you dislike my input - it was only intended to be constructive)

Comment: IMHO the /D switch is clearly described in the built in help: `/D:dirlist  Search a semicolon-delimited list of directories` and it is placed before the search string, so I don't understand what exactly is what "you found" about the /D switch (and what are the "commands that do NOT work")...

Comment: @Aacini in many languages, the order of attributes does not matter. I understand the documentation for `findstr` lists /D first. Yes I have no argument with the feature being documented, it just is not documented about the gotcha that the order of attributes matters. I do very little commandline work, so when I was cobbling a command, not aware the order made a difference, I was just adding the attributes as I got to them (and alphabetically, C precedes D). I was getting really frustrated and have shared my "found" experience for anyone else who doesn't work much with commandline.

Comment: The order of _optional_ attributes usually don't matters. The `findstr` documentation specify that `strings` part is _NOT_ optional and that you must place it after the _optional_ attributes and before the _optional_ filename list. If "your found" is that using a command without follow its usage format cause an error, then such a point is well documented. See [Command syntax](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true): _"Syntax appears in the order in which you must type a command and any parameters that follow it"_