# CMD script incorrect return code for end-of-line regex findstr command

Tags: regex, cmd, findstr

In a CMD script, I am trying to determine if a string has a "/" as the last character or not, using a regular expression with the findstr command. However, in **both** cases, I am getting a return code of 1.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET Project=/Folder1
ECHO.%Project% | findstr /R /C:"/$" 1>nul
ECHO %errorlevel%

SET Project=/Folder1/
ECHO.%Project% | findstr /R /C:"/$" 1>nul
ECHO %errorlevel%
```

Is there an issue here with the syntax?

Comment: There is a space between the variable and the pipe operator that is also included in the output of the `echo` command. Your line ending is a space.

Comment: @MC ND ... That was easy! Thank you!

Comment: N. B.: 1. The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`. 2. Better use the quoted syntax `set "VAR=Value"` to protect special characters and to avoid unintended trailing whitespaces. 3. Better replace `echo.` by `echo(` (although it looks odd), because the former might fail under some circumstances.

Comment: Related (can't find a real duplicate, but I'm sure I've already seen one once): [Piped Variable Into FINDSTR w/ Regular Expressions and Escaped Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10629139)