# Windows CMD checking variable if it has only capitals

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've got a variable and I need to check if it has only captials. For Example:

ABCDEF should match

But ABcdef shouldn't

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use findstr and errorlevel.  See the example below.  Note that you might expect `"^[A-Z]*$"` to work as the pattern, but it doesn't as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635740/why-does-findstr-not-handle-case-properly-in-some-circumstances).

Also note there is no space between `%X%`and `|` character, this is important.

```
C:\>SET X=ABCDEF
C:\>SET Y=ABcdef
C:\>echo %X%| findstr "^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*$"
ABCDEF

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
0

C:\>echo %Y%| findstr "^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*$"

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

Answer (score 2):

lessthanideal has a solution that will strictly verify that the string only contains capital letters. But I wonder if punctuation and or numerals should be allowed? If so, then it is better to check for the existence of a lower-case letter.

Also, you don't need to see the output of the FINDSTR command, so it can be redirected NUL. And you can use the `&&` and `||` operators to detect success and failure.

I am using `echo(` so that a blank line is echoed if the variable is undefined instead of `ECHO is on.`. Most people use `echo.`, but that form can fail under some circumstances, and `echo(` never fails.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set x=ABC_123
set y=AbC_123
echo(%x%|findstr /v "[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]" >nul && (
  echo %x% is Valid
) || (
  echo %x% is Invalid
)
echo(%y%|findstr /v "[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]" >nul && (
  echo %y% is Valid
) || (
  echo %y% is Invalid
)
```