# Pipe and Filter

Tags: filter, cmd, pipe, command-prompt

I am new to the command prompt want to know how all the command works …

I want to know how to apply pipe and filter in `cmd` to go through the directory and print only those files/folders that were created on a particular date, and want to use a data that occurs 2 -3 times within the files and folders of your test directory.

Comment: Please read this first: [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html).

Answer (score 22):

Go to **Start>Help and support** enter `command prompt` in the box and press the magnifying glass symbol at the end. Then select `Command Reference Overview [H1S]` from the list displayed. This will show the commands available.

Obviously, there are other articles that may be of aid as other selections.

Generally, typing

```
commandname /?
```

from the prompt will show (often cryptic) help

---

Essentially, the pipe symbol, `|` is used to direct the output of one command to the input of a second, so

```
dir | sort
```

for instance takes the screen-output of the `DIR` command and `SORT`s it.

The next question uses the critical term `created`. Each file may have THREE different times, the time the file was `created`, the time the file was last `written` to and the time the file was last `accessed`. It's possible to access all three times, but the default is the time last `written`. This is the normal time reported by DIR, and can variously be referred to as the `file time` or the `update time` amongst other terms.

Hence, to list the files (using the common `written` date) and select on a particular date, try

```
dir | find "dateyourequire"
```

where you need to replace `dateyourequire` with the target date, in the format matching that displayed by your `DIR` command. **BTW** commands are **NOT** case-sensitive - with one important exception.

Now date-format is a whole new ballgame, and you need to be very careful because the date shown is according to local convention. Some people use `DD/MM/YY` for instance - others use `MM-DD-YY` and there are many others. If you are discussing date and time, you need to say **EVERY TIME** the convention you are using.

---

You need to explain what you mean by your `data that occurs 2 -3 times` point. I can make neither head nor tail of it. Examples are usually a good way.

Comment: Also worth noting, if all you're trying to do is kill some process you could do - `C:\>Taskkill /IM firefox.exe /F` or `C:\>Taskkill /PID 12345 /F`

The `/f` kills the process by force. `PID` is process ID which you could find by doing `tasklist` and the `IM` I think is instance multiples (not sure though) - but you can use it to kill all running instances, so go figure!

Answer (score 20):

```
<your_command> | findstr "search_string*"
```

you can use parameter like `/I` `/B` etc. you can also use **Regular expression** for more information about `findstr` please see the reference `help findstr`

Answer (score 1):

To use regular expressions, these two examples for `tem` and `me` may help.

Given these folders inside `C:\tmp\Regex_Test`

```bash
C:\tmp\Regex_Test>tree
C:.
├───atem
├───atem1
├───tem
├───temA
└───xtemB
```

List the content of the directory `C:\tmp\Regex_Test` and filter for every entry that has `tem` somewhere.

```bash
C:\tmp\Regex_Test>dir | findstr /R tem
20.03.2024  10:37    <DIR>          atem
20.03.2024  10:37    <DIR>          atem1
20.03.2024  10:36    <DIR>          tem
20.03.2024  10:36    <DIR>          temA
20.03.2024  10:36    <DIR>          xtemB
```

Another example, list all entries that contain `me` and does have at least one character in front and at the end. This will not find a folder named `me`

```bash
C:\Windows>dir | findstr /R .me.
 Volume in Laufwerk C: hat keine Bezeichnung.
 Volumeseriennummer: 861F-B705
07.12.2019  11:14    <DIR>          GameBarPresenceWriter
16.06.2023  23:37    <DIR>          ImmersiveControlPanel
01.10.2023  14:19    <DIR>          SensorFramework
```

Comment: @Wolf thanks for pointing that out. The updated sample should be a better match.

Comment: We should be aware of [some undocumented features and limitations of `findstr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/2932052) (especially [regarding regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2635740/2932052)).