# grep in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, grep, findstr

I am trying to write a Windows batch file that will look through a specific html index file that looks something like this (simplified)

```
<a href=emergency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=EmeRgency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=Emergency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=EMERGENCY.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=E911.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=e911.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
```

and print all links whose filenames contain any uppercase letters so that they may be corrected not to so include any.

The following works in unix:

```
$ grep -v '^<a href=[^A-Z]*\.htm' helpindex.htm
<a href=EmeRgency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=Emergency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=EMERGENCY.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=E911.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
```

(the -v reverses the match)

But using the UnxUtils grep under Windows, which is a direct port of unix grep, I can't come up with a way of quoting the regex that works.  This would be necessary to use it in a batch file.  I've tried ', " with no joy and also the -E switch.  Is there any way to do this using this particular toolset?

@janos led me to the findstr command in Windows but it still doesn't work.  Looking at the findstr help I see:

> FINDSTR [/B] [/E] [/L] [/R] [/S] [/I] [/X] [/V] [/N] [/M] [/O] [/P]
>   [/F:file]
>           [/C:string] [/G:file] [/D:dir list] [/A:color attributes] [/OFF[LINE]]
>           strings [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]
>
> ...
>   /V         Prints only lines that do not contain a match. 
>   ...
>   /C:string  Uses specified string as a literal search string. ...
>
> Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is
>   prefixed with /C.  For example, 'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y' searches
>   for "hello" or "there" in file x.y.  'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y'
>   searches for "hello there" in file x.y.

However, this doesn't work either:

```
C:\home\sftp>findstr /V  /C:"^<a href=[^A-Z]*\.htm" helpindex.htm
<a href=emergency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=EmeRgency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=Emergency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=EMERGENCY.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=E911.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=e911.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
```

Either findstr is garbage or there is some subtle difference from grep.

Comment: This works for me in the version that comes with Git Bash. You could also try the native windows commands `find.exe` and `findstr.exe`. They are similar to `grep` (nothing to do with the UNIX `find`)

Comment: find does regex? I didn't know that.

Comment: findstr looks like it should work but it doesn't : findstr /V  '^<a href=[^A-Z]*\.htm' helpindex.htm produces mp results, not the four lines that uniz grep does.

Comment: I don't have a windows now to test it, but one of them needs the patterns enclosed within double quotes, even if it looks unnecessary, like `"simpleterm"`. I don't remember if it was `find` or `findstr`, watch our for that.

Answer (score 7):

This works fine for me in Windows command console:

```
grep -v "^<a href=[^A-Z]*\.htm" helpindex.htm
```

FINDSTR does not work with `[^A-Z]` because it uses a non-standard collation sequence: See [Why does findstr not handle case properly (in some circumstances)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2635740/1012053)

You can use FINDSTR to get your desired output using:

```
findstr /rvc:"^<a href=[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*\.htm" helpindex.htm
```

The /C option is needed to force the entire string to be considered one search term.

The /R option is needed to force interpretation of the search term as a regex. The default for the /C option is a string literal.

You might want to have a look at [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053). There is a long list of "gotchas"

**Edit**

UnxUtils is an old, outdated distribution of GNU unix utilities for Windows. You should get newer releases from GNU Coreutils: see [Difference between UnxUtils and GNU CoreUtils](https://superuser.com/q/168202/109090)

I believe I got my distribution of GNU Coreutils from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm. I'm not sure if that is the most up-to-date package, but it should solve your grep problem. It provides a convenient package of many utilities.

Another option is to get individual GNU utilities for Windows from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html

Comment: grep didn't work for me.  Are you using the unxutils version?  But adding the /R switch to findstr and spelling out the alphabet did.  THANKS!

Comment: @SteveCohen - I'm using GNU grep 2.5.1 for Windows

Comment: Mine was 2.4.2 from UnxUtils

Answer (score 2):

You may use my FindRepl.bat program that works as you want. For example:

```
> type helpindex.htm
<a href=emergency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=EmeRgency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=Emergency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=EMERGENCY.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=E911.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=e911.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>

> FindRepl /V "^<a href=[^A-Z]*\.htm" < helpindex.htm
<a href=EmeRgency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=Emergency.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=EMERGENCY.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
<a href=E911.htm>Emergency Calls</a><br>
```

You may download FindRepl.bat from [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697)