# Batch - Display a line from TXT File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple batch file, which reads a txt file containing simple lines and looks for a specific word in it, for example "Error". If the word is in the txt file, it opens a CMD with the message "FOUND". So far so good.

Now...is there a way to show the whole line in the CMD containing the searched word, for example:

"1. There is an Error in building A."

Thanks...

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057751/grep-in-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

Use the `findstr` command, like this:

```
findstr /l /s Error file.txt
```

Comment: Your answer does not directly answer the question asked. Also it appears to be utilising a strange choice of options.