# Generate help files

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I wanted to make help generator for all command in `help` in Windows cmd and write it to separate files. So you are asking /? on all commands that are on the list when you type `help` in cmd.
Here are the main part of my code:

```
rem mypath - it's a folder where I put my results
rem In help all command are written by capitals letters
for /f "tokens=1 usebackq" %%i in (`help^|findstr /B /R "[QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM][QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM]"`) do (
  if NOT "%%i"=="GRAFTABL" (
    if NOT "%%i"=="DISKPART" (
      if NOT "%%i"=="SC" (
        help %%i > !mypath!\%%i.txt
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I use all sequence from [Q..M] in my Regular exp because there are some problems with just set of [A-Z]
But the problem is that in my FOR and IF files - there are help for REM command. Does anyone have any idea why is it so ?
To fix it I use:

```
FOR/? >%mypath%\FOR.txt
IF/? >%mypath%\IF.txt
```

But I can't understand why it is so.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted in your question gives the correct result for me (even before I reformatted it a bit).

See [Why does findstr not handle case properly (in some circumstances)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2635740/1012053) for an explanation of why [A-Z] does not work properly with FINDSTR. For an exhaustive list of known FINDSTR quirks, see [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053)

A better way to filter out command names is to look for lines that begin with at least one non-space character, followed by any number of additional non-space characters, followed by 2 spaces.

If you want to ignore certain commands, you can simply use an additional FINDSTR with the /V option.

The solution becomes a reasonable one liner that can run from the command prompt without a batch script:

```
for /f %A in ('help^|findstr /rc:"^[^ ][^ ]*  "^|findstr /v "GRAFTABL DISKPART SC"') do @help %A >%A.txt
```

Or as code that can be plugged into your script:

```
for /f %%A in (
  'help^|findstr /rc:"^[^ ][^ ]*  "^|findstr /v "GRAFTABL DISKPART SC"'
) do help %%A >"!mypath!\%%A.txt"
```

***EDIT - 2015-10-11***

The first and last lines of HELP output start with the word `For` (mixed case), on my English machine. That word happens to be a valid command with help, so the FOR.TXT file gets created 3 times.

I presume that all languages use mixed case for the first and last line. It is not hard to refine the FINDSTR filter to exclude any line where the 2nd character is space or a lower case character:

```
for /f %A in ('help^|findstr /rvc:"^.[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ]"^|findstr /v "GRAFTABL DISKPART SC"') do @help %A >%A.txt
```

Comment: Great example, but what mean `^[^ ][^ ]`. This mean exclude two consecutive white space at the beginning of a line?

Comment: No, `[^ ]` means any character except a space.

Comment: My help command start with 2 lines without spaces in the first word. I don't understand how you able to exclude it.

Comment: @paul - I don't, but it doesn't matter. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: After comparing your command and this:`help|findstr /rvc:"^.[a-z ]` I am definitively lost :D

Comment: @Paul - Oops, I had a bug with some inadvertent spaces. All fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your issue, but this worked correctly for me and I found a simpler regular expression:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('help^|findstr /B /R [A-Z][^^^^o]') do (
if NOT "%%i"=="GRAFTABL" (
    if NOT "%%i"=="DISKPART" (
        if NOT "%%i"=="SC" (
            help %%i > %%i.txt
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I still have file with help for `FOR` and for `IF` with the help for the command `REM` somehow. And could you explain your regex [^^^^o] - you invert set 4 times ?

Comment: Both the cmd prompt and regex process the escapes, so to get *one* caret the single caret is escaped, then the two carets are escaped again.  I found with just [A-Z] I got two extra "For" lines, so I added that for "do not match o as second character".  I tried [A-Z][A-Z] for two capitals, but it still matched "For".  Maybe ranges are case insensitive, or just a bug.  FYI, I ran yours and mine and neither had REM in the FOR.txt or IF.txt files.  Try "@echo help %%i > %%i.txt" so view the commands you are generating.

Comment: This is locale dependent. It works fine for English, but will not work for other languages.