# How to launch help from .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
`@echo off
 chcp 1251>nul
 help | findstr /b [A-Z] > 1.txt
 for /F "tokens=1*" %%1 in ('1.txt') do (help %%1) > %%1.txt
 del 1.txt `
```

I guess it should be done somehow this way but it doesnt work. This should "take" the name of a command and then use it for "help command"(help if for e,g) and then type it(With echo ofc) in the txt file with name of a command.

Comment: @aschipfl - Absolutely not true, despite what the MS docs say. Almost any character can be used as FOR variable. More info at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8520993/1012053

Comment: Thanks, @dbenham, just found it out myself, so I'm going to delete the comment...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate help files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363893/generate-help-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
@echo off
chcp 1251 > nul
help | findstr /B ".[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]" > 1.txt
for /F %%1 in (1.txt) do (help %%1) > %%1.txt
del 1.txt
```

There were `''` around `1.txt` in the set of `for`, so it was interpreted as a command rather than a text file.

`tokens=1*` is not necessary as you are using the first token only, so `tokens=1`, which is the default, is enough.

---

However, you can do the same without a temporary file `1.txt` like this:

```
@echo off
chcp 1251 > nul
for /F %%1 in ('help ^| findstr /B ".[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]"') do (help %%1) > %%1.txt
```

---

Both scripts above require administrator privileges to run without interruptions, because of the `diskpart` command, which requires such privileges even for displaying the help text, stupidly.

The `SC` command will halt the scripts due to a `y`/`n` user prompt whether or not to display help for sub-commands `query` and `queryex` too. To suppress that, you could try to pipe such a letter into `help %%1`, that is, to prepend it with `echo y|` or `echo n|`.

Comment: that findstr regex doesn't work, `for /F %1 in ('help^|findstr /b [A-Z][A-Z]') do @echo %1` is same as `for /F %1 in ('help') do @echo %1` If you have grep I suggest `help|grep -o -E "(^[A-Z][A-Z]+)"`

Comment: I'll never understand `findstr`... I changed the regex to "\<[A-Z][A-Z]*\>", so it should return lines with upper-case words only... I don't have `grep`, but I'll definitely check it out -- thanks for the hint, @Paul

Comment: Also I would add an intermediate conversion for the problems of encoding of regional languages `do ( help %%1>"%tmp%\%%1.tmp"
  cmd /U /C type %tmp%\%%1.tmp>%%1.TXT
)`

Answer (score 1):

This is repeat of the following that Rob van der Woude coded up..

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=allhelp_nt

I think there are a couple variations on his site as well.

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/allhelp.php

Thanks.