# want to copy names of files to text in a directory based on their file extension

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to copy names of files to text in a directory based on their file extension.

As of now I am using `dir /b >i67.txt` which works fine for me but its not resolving problem of specific file extensions.

Can someone help me in getting a batch script for the same.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. But It seems you can sort file list using `dir /b /o:e`. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the following command, run it in the context of the directory which contains your files:

```
dir /b /s /-p *.txt /o:n | findstr /E .txt > i67.txt
```

Using the above code example, you will be able to find all `*.txt` files in the directory and output the results into the `i67.txt` file (will be outputted to the same directory).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have done it. Here is what I am using now:

dir /b | findstr [a-z].*ovr>i67.txt && dir /b | findstr [a-z].*inc>>i67.txt && dir /b | findstr [a-z].*dat>>i67.txt

What it does?? --- It copies all names(remember,only name except files itself which are ending with extension .ovr .dat and .cpi ) present in a directory and copy it to a text file(here name is i67.txt)

Comment: @aks_webmethods - That will not do what you think. See the end of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22282941/1012053).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple file masks within one DIR /B command. Based on your comment to Yair Nevet's answer, it seems you want the following extensions: `.ovr`, `.inc`, and `.dat`. That can be done simply using:

```
dir /b /s *.ovr *.inc *.dat >i67.txt
```

If the files are on an NTFS volume that has short 8.3 names enabled, then you might get additional undesired file extensions if you have any file extensions longer than 4 characters that begin with your wanted extension. For example `someName.data` would show up in your output because it most likely would have a short name of `SOMENA~1.DAT` that matches your file mask.

You can prevent short name inclusion by piping the output to FINDSTR. The `/L` option forces a literal search as opposed to regular expressions, the `/I` option ignores case, and the `/E` option matches only the end of each line. Multiple search terms are delimited by spaces.

```
dir /b /s *.ovr *.inc *.dat | findstr /lie ".ovr .inc .dat"
```

---

Regarding your following comment:

> Here is what I am using now: dir /b | findstr [a-z].*ovr>i67.txt &&
>   dir /b | findstr [a-z].*inc>>i67.txt && dir /b | findstr
>   [a-z].*dat>>i67.txt What it does?? --- It copies all
>   names(remember,only name except files itself which are ending with
>   extension .ovr .dat and .cpi ) present in a directory and copy it to a
>   text file(here name is i67.txt)

That will not actually do what you want for several reasons.

- Windows file names are not case sensitive. Windows would treat NAME.OVR and name.ovr the same, so you should as well. That requires the `/I` option.
- There is nothing in your search to anchor ovr to the extension. It will look for your pattern anywhere within the file name. And the dot is a meta character that represents any character - not a literal dot. The asterisk allows the dot to match any number of characters.

I can't be sure, but it looks like perhaps you only want to match files that begin with a letter. The following modification to my answer should do the trick:

```
dir /b /s *.ovr *.inc *.dat | findstr /ri "^[a-z].*\.ovr$ ^[a-z].*\.inc$ ^[a-z].*\.dat$"
```

The `\R` option forces a regular expression match instead of a literal. It is the default behavior for the given search, but it is a good idea to be explicit with regard to regex vs literal search.

`^` anchors the search to the beginning of the name

`[a-z]` matches any letter (sort of). Remember it is not case sensitive because of the `/I` option. Without the `/I` option, it would not match upper case `Z`. See [Why does findstr not handle case properly (in some circumstances)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2635740/1012053) for an explanation.

`.*` matches any number of characters, without restriction

`\.` matches a dot literal, marking the beginning of your extension

Then comes your extension

`$` anchors the match to the end of the name