# Regex to match a variable in Batch scripting

Tags: regex, batch-file

```
@echo off

SET /p var=Enter: 
echo %var% | findstr /r "^[a-z]{2,3}$">nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (echo does not contain) else (echo contains)
pause
```

I'm trying to valid a input which should contain 2 or 3 letters. But I tried all the possible answer, it only runs `if error level 1 (echo does not contain)`.

Can someone help me please. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`findstr` has no full REGEX Support. Especially no `{Count}`. You have to use a workaround:

```
echo %var%|findstr /r "^[a-z][a-z]$ ^[a-z][a-z][a-z]$"
```

which searches for `^[a-z][a-z]$` OR `^[a-z][a-z][a-z]$`

(Note: there is no space between `%var%` and `|` - it would be part of the string)

Answer (score 5):

Since other answers are not against `findstr`, howabout running `cscript`? This allows us to use a proper Javascript regex engine.

```sh
@echo off
SET /p var=Enter: 
cscript //nologo match.js "^[a-z]{2,3}$" "%var%"
if errorlevel 1 (echo does not contain) else (echo contains)
pause
```

Where `match.js` is defined as:

```js
if (WScript.Arguments.Count() !== 2) {
  WScript.Echo("Syntax: match.js regex string");
  WScript.Quit(1);
}
var rx = new RegExp(WScript.Arguments(0), "i");
var str = WScript.Arguments(1);
WScript.Quit(str.match(rx) ? 0 : 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34525752/5047996) is correct in terms of support for regular expression. However, it does not regard a bug of `findstr` concerning character classes like `[a-z]` -- see [this answer by dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767815/5047996).

To overcome this you need to specify this ( I know it looks terrible):

```
echo %var%|findstr /R "^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz][abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]$ ^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz][abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz][abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]$"
```

This truly matches only strings consisting of two or three lower-case letters. Using ranges `[a-z]` would match lower- *and* upper-case letters except `Z`.

For a complete list of bugs and features of `findstr`, reference [this post by dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/5047996).

Comment: "_(I know it looks terrible):_" [Truer words...](https://www.goenglish.com/TruerWordsWereNeverSpoken.asp) 

Answer (score 0):

errorlevel is that number OR HIGHER.

Use following.

```
if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo It's just one.
```

See  this

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo It's just one.

C:\Windows\system32>if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 echo It's just ohh.
It's just ohh.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

If Higher than one and not higher than n+1 (2 in this case)

Comment: The first sentence says _errorlevel is that number OR HIGHER_ or _NOT that number or higher_

Comment: `findstr` errorlevel doesn't give the count, but only `0` (found at least one) or `1` (found none).