# Regex in Batch for MAC of format xxxx.xxxx.xxxx

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I have been trying to parse a mac with format "xxxx[Delimiter]xxxx[Delimiter]xxxx" where "x" is in [0-9,A-F,a-f] and "[Delimiter]" is in [:,.,-]. I have tried the following code and have referred the example with title [Regex to match a variable in Batch scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260467/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-a-mac-address) and [What is a regular expression for a MAC Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524390/regex-to-match-a-variable-in-batch-scripting).

```
set MACAddr=012a.23fa.5ffc
If [%MACAddr%] EQU [] (
echo MAC Address is not set. Please set it to proceed.
) else (
echo %MACAddr%|findstr /r "^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:.-]?){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$"
if errorlevel 1 (echo Mac %MACAddr% is not of same Format as xxxx.xxxx.xxxx) else ( pause )
)
```

also tried this

```
echo %MACAddr%|findstr /r "^([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})([:.-])([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})([:.-])([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})$"
```

But it only runs `if errorlevel 1 (echo Mac %MACAddr% is not of same Format as xxxx.xxxx.xxxx)`.Please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: sorry, `findstr` has no full REGEX support. Especially no `{x}`. See `findstr /?` - and try to be not too disappointed.

Comment: @Anu, please read the help for the command before posting questions.

Comment: So are you trying to match: `012a.23fa.5ffc` & `F8-CA-B8-07-5A-D0` & `d4:be:d9:97:74:c2`?  I have never seen mac address expressed as `012a.23fa.5ffc`. Would make more sense to be consistent: `01.2a.23.fa.5f.fc`

Comment: @Squashman I was trying to match 012a.23fa.5ffc or 012a-23fa-5ffc or 012a:23fa:5ffc.Actually this format is followed by my router.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findstr` has a very limited subset of REGEX (see `for /?`)

Your request can be formulated as:

```
findstr /ri "^[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F].[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F].[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]$"
```

where `.` means "any char". If you want to break it down to just `;`, `.` and `-` as delimiters, use `[;.-]` instead of `.`. If the delimiters may be there or may not be there, use `[;.-]*` instead (where `*` means "zero or more" - sorry, there is no `?` "none or one" with `findstr`.)

Comment: Hi @Stephan, that worked brilliantly!! Although its true that findstr does have a limited subset of REGEX , but this worked out ..thanks!. :)

Answer (score 3):

As [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082) already mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788129), `findstr` does not have full RegEx support.

So grouping (`(`/`)`), alternatives (`|`), repetitions (`{`/`}`) and options (`?`) are not supported.

There is an additional limitation that needs to be taken into account: the number of character classes (`[`/`]`) is limited to 15, so specifying 16 or more results in an error.
And not enough, character classes are buggy, they might match unexpected characters; for instance, the range `[0-9]` matches the decimal figures `0` to `9`, but also characters `²` and `³`; the range `[A-Z]` (without the `/I` option) matches also lower-case letters erroneously, like `z`, and also some other characters, like `Á` or `á`, depending on the current code page.

Refer to the great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868) by [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053) concerning all the bugs and limitations of `findstr`.

---

To work around all that, you can specify multiple search strings, like `findstr /R "search_string1 search_string2"` (white-space-separated list) or `findstr /R /C:"search string1" /C:"search string2"` (this even allows white-spaces to be part of the search strings).

I would do your task like this:

```cmd
echo %MACAddr%| (findstr /I /X /R ^
    /C:"[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]" ^
    /C:"[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]" ^
    /C:"[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]" ^
    /C:"[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]" ^
    /C:"[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]" ^
    /C:"[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]" ^

)
```

You can also use the syntax without `/C`, but it is terrible to read:

```cmd
echo %MACAddr%| findstr /I /X /R "[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F] [0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F] [0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F] [0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F] [0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F] [0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]"
```

You can put the search strings into a text file (say `MACAddrRegEx.txt`) and use this syntax:

```cmd
echo %MACAddr%| findstr /I /X /R /G:"MACAddrRegEx.txt"
```

And the content of `MACAddrRegEx.txt` is:

> ```cmd
> [0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]
> [0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]
> [0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F][0-9A-F]
> [0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\.[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]
> [0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]:[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]
> [0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]-[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]
> ```

Remove the former three search strings if you do not want to accept strings with hexadecimal digits in groups of four; remove latter three ones if you do not want to accept strings in groups of two.

The aforementioned bug concerning upper- and lower-case-matching against letter ranges does not apply here since the `/I` option is specified, which defines to do case-insensitive searches. However, the other range-related bugs are ignored here as otherwise, the search strings became extensively long (note that `[0-9]` needed to be changed to `[0123456789]` in order to match decimal digits only; same for letters) and so the length limit was going to be exceeded.

Comment: Shouldn't all these classes `[0-9A-Z]` better be `[0-9A-F]` ?

Comment: Yes, of course, @LotPings, thank you! I seem to have confused myself with the `[A-Z]` example at the first section... :-/

Answer (score 1):

You know how when you get a problem like this, you just have to keep going until you get a solution?

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

:: This simply tests various addresses

FOR %%D IN (":" "." "-" "#") DO FOR %%T IN (
.012a.23fa.5ffc
012a.23fa.5ffc.
012a.23fa.5ffc
012a.23fa
012a.23fa.5ffc.0123
01ka.23fa.5ffc
012a.23ga.5ffc
012a.23fa.5pfc
012a1.23fa.5ffc
012a.263fa.5ffc
012a.23fa.58ffc
1.2.3
03ed.2.f
) DO (
 set "MACAddr=%%T"
 SET "macaddr=!macaddr:.=%%~D!"
 CALL :testmacaddr
)
SET "macaddr="
CALL :testmacaddr

GOTO :eof

:testmacaddr
SET "invalid="
SET "valid="
If NOT DEFINED MACAddr SET "invalid=MACADDR not set"&GOTO report
FOR %%d IN (":" "." "-") DO (
 IF "%macaddr:~0,1%"=="%%~d" SET "invalid=Initial"
 IF "%macaddr:~-1%"=="%%~d" SET "invalid=Terminal"
 SET "control="tokens=1-4delims=%%~d""
 CALL :tokenise
)
:report
IF NOT DEFINED valid IF NOT DEFINED invalid SET "invalid=Incorrect octet count"
:: pad 'macaddr' with a goodly number of spaces,
:: show the first 20 character of the result and the 'invalid' value

SET "macaddr=%macaddr%                          "
ECHO %macaddr:~0,20% : %invalid%
GOTO :EOF

:tokenise
FOR /f %control% %%p IN ("%macaddr%") DO (
 IF "%%s"=="" IF "%%r" neq "" (
  SET /a octets=1
  CALL :validate %%p %%q %%r
 )
)

GOTO :eof

:validate
ECHO %1|FINDSTR /r /x /i "[0-9a-f]">NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO valok
ECHO %1|FINDSTR /r /x /i "[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]">NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO valok
ECHO %1|FINDSTR /r /x /i "[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]">NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO valok
ECHO %1|FINDSTR /r /x /i "[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]">NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "invalid=Octet %octets%"&GOTO :eof
:valok
shift
SET /a octets+=1
IF %octets% lss 4 GOTO validate
SET "valid=Y"

GOTO :eof
```

So - the first part simply generates a series of "possible" entries for testing. The routine `:testmacaddr` with `macaddr` assigned to a test string actually does the work and the part after label `:report` reports results - if `invalid` is defined, then the supplied `macaddr` is invalid for the reason in `%invalid%`

The `for %%d` loop checks for initial or terminal delimiters and establishes the control string for the inner loop in the `:tokenise` routine.

The `:tokenise` routine examines the supplied address for the first 4 tokens using the current delimiter, assigning the octets to %%p..%%s. Since we want exactly 3, then `%%s` must be empty and `%%r` not-empty to require further validation using `:validate`

`:validate` examines each octet for an `/x` exact match `/i` case-insensitive to the `/r` regular expression 1,2,3 or 4 hex-digits. If the octet fails all of these tests, `invalid` is set to the failing octet number. If all octets pass then `valid` is set to `Y`

So, if there are no failing conditions and the `:validate` routine was passed once, then the value is valid.

Comment: @Mangoo Thanks. I haven't tried this out yet but this seems more generic than previous answer so I will try this out surely. :)